# How to query the actual value in Entity Framework core when using a Value Converter?

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

We have a fairly simple situation where an EF Core entity contains a value object that we map to a string:

```
builder.Property(_ => _.Nummer)
    .HasConversion(i => i.ToString(), i => ZijdeNummer.FromString(i))
    .IsRequired().HasMaxLength(9);
```

This works fine for retrieval and storage, but for filtering we're looking for a way to filter rows by substring. If it'd be a normal `string` column you can simply do something like this:

```
dbSet.TheTable.Where(t => t.Nummer.Contains("some text")).ToList()
```

Obviously the custom `ZijdeNummer` doesn't contain a recognized `.Contains()` method. I've tried using `.ToString().Contains()` but alas, this also doesn't work.

Finally, I've also tried accessing the column as if it were a shadow-property:

```
dbSet.TheTable.Where(t => EF.Property<string>(t, "Nummer").Contains("some text"))
```

But it won't be fooled as it still knows that `EF.Property<T>(t, "Nummer")` is not actually a string :(

Is there a way to make EF-Core just query the raw column type?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out this is much easier than you'd expect. Simply cast the type to string (if no conversion exists, then first cast to object) and perform the comparison:

```
dbSet.TheTable.Where(t => ((string)(object)t.Nummer).Contains("some text")).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks for this I never would have thought to do this myself. This is particularly useful when trying to do the common task of trying to sum a group of timespan fields which are mapped from a long holding ticks.

Comment: Please mark this post as answer, even if it's your own. This helps users better find it when they see this question has an accepted answer.

Comment: Will do! Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score -1):

There has to be an easier way, right?
I wouldn't want casts to object -> string all over my queries

Comment: This only applies when you want to use a string method on the type. For normal queries you don't have to do this. If you find yourself using a lot of string methods on the type, you may want to consider creating an extension method that creates the expression.

Comment: Your post should rather be a 'comment' on @Robba's answer, not an 'answer'.