# How to read data ignoring ValueConverters

Tags: entity-framework-core

I got a custom `ValueConverter` that serializes objects as JSON and stores them as a `STRING` in the database. This works well, but for some use cases I need to read the data as it is in the database, ignoring the `ValueConverter`. How to do that?

Unfortunatly, the API of a `ValueConverter` does not allow to disable a conversion, because my implementation has to return a value of type `object` and can't return a `STRING`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe the "use cases" to show the limitations you have on the `ValueConverter`. It might be a simple boolean flag inside your `ValueConverter` to enable or disable any conversions.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71705306/2900970) that is applicable to my problem. Use a projection and cast the property to its database type (`STRING`in this example).

EmployeeSet.Select(e => new {Name = e.Name, RawData = (string)e.Data})