# EF Core 8: Entity with Value Object - LINQ Translation Issue

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

My project is based on .NET 8 and EF Core 8.0.2.

I have a `Customer` entity that does not have any Id as primary key but has a composite key with combination of FirstName, LastName, DateOfBirth. This entity has a value object class with name `Email`, and email class inherit from `ValueObject`.

This is my code:

```
public sealed class Customer : BaseEntity
{
    public Customer( Email email) : this()
    {
        Email = email ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(email));
    }

    private Customer()
    { } // For EF Configuration

    public Email Email { get; private set; }

    public void UpdateDetails(Email email)
    {
        Email = email ?? Email;
    }
}
```

```
using CSharpFunctionalExtensions;

namespace Mc2.CrudTest.Domain.ValueObjects;

public class Email : ValueObject
{
    public string Value { get; }

    public Email(string value)
    {
        Validate(value);
        Value = value;
    }

    private static void Validate(string value)
    {
        if (!IsValidEmail(value))
            throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(ErrorMessages.InvalidFormatExceptionMsg, nameof(Email)));
    }

    private static bool IsValidEmail(string email)
    {
        Regex regex = new(RegexHelper.EmailRegexPattern);
        return regex.IsMatch(email.Trim());
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<IComparable> GetEqualityComponents()
    {
        yield return Value;
    }
}
```

And this is my EF Core configuration for this value type and entity:

```
public class CustomerConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Customer>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(x => x.Email)
            .HasConversion(x => x.Value, x => new Email(x))
            .HasColumnName(nameof(Email))
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(CustomerValidationRules.CustomerEmailMaxLength)
            .IsUnicode(false); // Varchar

        // Unique constraints
        builder.HasIndex(c => c.Email).IsUnique();
    }
}
```

When I want to run this query:

```
return await _dbContext.Customers
            .Select(x => x.Email.Value)
            .AnyAsync(e => e.Equals(email));
```

but it throws this exception:

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet() .Any(c => c.Email.Value.Equals(__email_0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

What is the best solution for handle these types of value object?

I have used raw SQL queries but it is not solution. I expect to find config to properly handle value objects for entities in EF Core.

Comment: This is not specific to ValueObject. If `Email` were a class you'd get the same exception. Comparisons in EF LINQ queries should always be on primitive values (email.Value) because there's no inherit SQL translation of classes etc. into SQL.

Comment: How should it be? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: You can modify your LINQ query to include a Where clause that filters the Email values in memory, and then use AnyAsync to check if any matching emails exist

return await _dbContext.Customers.Where(x => x.Email.Value == email).AnyAsync();

I have not tested (Typing out of my head) so I added as comment an not answer

Comment: thanks for comment. How @ASisic should I implement your idea? 

I confused about config and how to implement it to solve the issue with translation.

Comment: You shouldn't be specifying `.Value` anywhere in a linq query, since the value conversion is doing the heavy lifting there. Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71704235/how-to-query-the-actual-value-in-entity-framework-core-when-using-a-value-conver

Comment: @JeremyLakeman thank you. 

Ef convert to sql like this.

' exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [c].[FirstName], [c].[LastName], [c].[DateOfBirth], [c].[BankAccountNumber], [c].[Email], [c].[PhoneNumber]
FROM [Customers] AS [c]
WHERE CAST([c].[Email] AS nvarchar(max)) = @__email_0',N'@__email_0 nvarchar(4000)',@__email_0=N'a@s.com'

'


Is it correct? my Email column is varchar 50.
Or does it have any better approach?